# Magento - overriden grid with new column does not populate new value for row

Tags: magento, adminhtml

Extending core functionality, adding new column.  Grid gets built, query builds w/ data but the when the row is generated it fails to add populate the 'visibility' cell in the row.  Thoughts?

EDIT: For clarity.

## output of zend_debug($row)

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product#751 (28) {
  protected $_cacheTag =>  string(15) "catalog_product"
  protected $_eventPrefix =>  string(15) "catalog_product"
  protected $_eventObject =>  string(7) "product"
  protected $_canAffectOptions =>  bool(false)
  protected $_typeInstance =>  NULL
  protected $_typeInstanceSingleton =>  NULL
  protected $_linkInstance =>  NULL
  protected $_customOptions =>  array(0) {
  }
  protected $_urlModel =>  NULL
  protected $_errors =>  array(0) {
  }
  protected $_optionInstance =>  NULL
  protected $_options =>  array(0) {
  }
  protected $_reservedAttributes =>  NULL
  protected $_isDuplicable =>  bool(true)
  protected $_defaultValues =>  array(0) {
  }
  protected $_lockedAttributes =>  array(0) {
  }
  protected $_isDeleteable =>  bool(true)
  protected $_isReadonly =>  bool(false)
  protected $_resourceName =>  string(15) "catalog/product"
  protected $_resource =>  NULL
  protected $_resourceCollectionName =>  string(26) "catalog/product_collection"
  protected $_dataSaveAllowed =>  bool(true)
  protected $_isObjectNew =>  NULL
  protected $_data =>  array(13) {
    'entity_id' =>    string(4) "2384"
    'entity_type_id' =>    string(1) "4"
    'attribute_set_id' =>    string(1) "4"
    'type_id' =>    string(6) "simple"
    'sku' =>    string(0) ""
    'has_options' =>    string(1) "0"
    'required_options' =>    string(1) "0"
    'created_at' =>    string(19) "2012-06-22 16:19:32"
    'updated_at' =>    string(19) "2012-07-03 14:06:08"
    'position' =>    NULL
    'name' =>    string(25) "Games Site Test Product 4"
    'price' =>    string(8) "100.0000"
    'stock_item' =>    class Varien_Object#792 (5) {
      protected $_data =>      array(1) {
        ...
      }
      protected $_hasDataChanges =>      bool(false)
      protected $_origData =>      NULL
      protected $_idFieldName =>      NULL
      protected $_isDeleted =>      bool(false)
    }
  }
  protected $_hasDataChanges =>  bool(true)
  protected $_origData =>  array(12) {
    'entity_id' =>    string(4) "2384"
    'entity_type_id' =>    string(1) "4"
    'attribute_set_id' =>    string(1) "4"
    'type_id' =>    string(6) "simple"
    'sku' =>    string(0) ""
    'has_options' =>    string(1) "0"
    'required_options' =>    string(1) "0"
    'created_at' =>    string(19) "2012-06-22 16:19:32"
    'updated_at' =>    string(19) "2012-07-03 14:06:08"
    'position' =>    NULL
    'name' =>    string(25) "Games Site Test Product 4"
    'price' =>    string(8) "100.0000"
  }
  protected $_idFieldName =>  string(9) "entity_id"
  protected $_isDeleted =>  bool(false)
}
,
```

## sqdump (i added LIMIT 10)

```
mysql> SELECT `e`.*, `_table_position`.`position`, `_table_visibility`.`value` AS `visibility` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `_table_position` ON (_table_position.product_id=e.entity_id) AND (category_id=0) INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `_table_visibility` ON (_table_visibility.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (_table_visibility.attribute_id='89') AND (_table_visibility.store_id=0) limit 10;
+-----------+----------------+------------------+---------+---------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| entity_id | entity_type_id | attribute_set_id | type_id | sku     | has_options | required_options | created_at          | updated_at          | position | visibility |
+-----------+----------------+------------------+---------+---------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+
|         2 |              4 |                9 | simple  | PWOPER  |           0 |                0 | 2010-06-09 20:14:44 | 2012-01-09 19:20:06 |     NULL |          1 |
|         3 |              4 |                9 | simple  | PW20WCB |           0 |                0 | 2010-06-10 14:36:04 | 2012-07-03 16:46:09 |     NULL |          4 |
|        20 |              4 |                9 | simple  | PW5TBW  |           0 |                0 | 2010-06-28 15:44:23 | 2011-04-08 21:35:02 |     NULL |          1 |
|        21 |              4 |                9 | simple  | PWBJACK |           0 |                0 | 2010-06-28 15:51:35 | 2011-10-27 15:26:21 |     NULL |          1 |
|        22 |              4 |                9 | simple  | YK32006 |           0 |                0 | 2010-06-28 16:22:25 | 2012-07-03 16:47:46 |     NULL |          4 |
|        23 |              4 |                9 | simple  | YK32008 |           0 |                0 | 2010-06-28 16:30:51 | 2012-07-03 16:48:55 |     NULL |          4 |
|        24 |              4 |                9 | simple  | RFBURG  |           0 |                0 | 2010-06-28 16:37:12 | 2011-09-16 14:03:04 |     NULL |          4 |
|        25 |              4 |                9 | simple  | PW10EWJ |           0 |                0 | 2010-06-28 17:34:15 | 2011-08-11 15:43:49 |     NULL |          1 |
|        26 |              4 |                9 | simple  | PW10WJ  |           0 |                0 | 2010-06-28 17:39:26 | 2011-08-11 16:04:37 |     NULL |          4 |
|        27 |              4 |                9 | simple  | HDNG10  |           0 |                0 | 2010-06-28 17:48:00 | 2012-07-03 17:00:07 |     NULL |          4 |
+-----------+----------------+------------------+---------+---------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## _prepareCollection()

```
class My_CategoryFilters_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product {
... 
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    if ($this->getCategory()->getId()) {
        $this->setDefaultFilter(array('in_category'=>1));
    }
    #$store = $this->_getStore();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('store_id')
        #->addAttributeToSelect('visibility')
        ->addStoreFilter($this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
        ->joinField('position',
            'catalog/category_product',
            'position',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            'category_id='.(int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0),
            'left')
        ->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', 'entity_id', 'entity_id='.(int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0), 'inner')
        ;

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();

    if ($this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
        $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            $productIds = 0;
        }
        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$productIds));
    }

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

## _prepareColumns()

```
    $this->addColumn('visibility', array(
        'header'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Visibility'),
        'width'    => '100',
        'sortable' => false,
        'index'    => 'visibility',
        'type'     => 'options',
        'options'  => Mage::getModel('catalog/product_visibility')->getOptionArray(),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

My implementation extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product.  Because it extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product, I am very restricted as to what I can do w/ the extended methods.  The reason the new column's data does not appear is because the parent method has no access to the data (->addAttribute('visibility')).

In order to handle the new data, I need to extend Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid instead.  The widget provides more generalized methods for handling data.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the product collection `catalog/model/resource/product/collection.php` a few things I see that may be the culprit:

```
 /**
 * Apply limitation filters to collection
 * Method allows using one time category product index table (or product website table)
 * for different combinations of store_id/category_id/visibility filter states
 * Method supports multiple changes in one collection object for this parameters
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
 */
protected function _applyProductLimitations()
{
    $this->_prepareProductLimitationFilters();
```

It appears Magento is blocking and/or routing the `visibility` field from the collection.

Further looking into `_prepareProductLimitationFilters()` method itself reveals:

```
/**
 * Apply front-end price limitation filters to the collection
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
 */
public function applyFrontendPriceLimitations()
{
    $this->_productLimitationFilters['use_price_index'] = true;
    if (!isset($this->_productLimitationFilters['customer_group_id'])) {
        $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        $this->_productLimitationFilters['customer_group_id'] = $customerGroupId;
    }
    if (!isset($this->_productLimitationFilters['website_id'])) {
        $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($this->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();
        $this->_productLimitationFilters['website_id'] = $websiteId;
    }
    $this->_applyProductLimitations();
    return $this;
}
```

How to get around this without causing havoc on the "reasoning" as to why this I'm not sure of.